# How to explain usage of 照得上 站得下

Tags: classical-chinese

could you explain, please, why we use 上 with some verbs? and with some 下？does it depends on the verb? 广场上停得下10辆车 10 cars can be placed here. 天安门照得上吗？Can you take picture of Tiananmen?

Comment: see grammars on complements of direction (趋向补语）e.g.＂实用现代汉语语法＂［上］１。趋向意义（一）：表示人或物体，通过动作由低处向高处移动，没有确定的立足点。例如：（１）龙梅把羊 _赶上_ 山。说这句话时，立足点（比如说话人的位置）可以在＂山上＂，也可以在＂山下＂（＂下、进、出、回。。。＂等也都没有确定的立足点，下文不在说明）。（２）气球慢慢飞上天空。２。趋向意义（二）；表示通过动作，人或物体向立足点移动－－趋近立足点。例如：（１）老王叫我，我就快步 _走上_ 前问他有什么事。３。结果意义（一）－－基本结果意义：表示接触、附着以至固定。例如：（１）请你把门 _关上_ 。（２）我用一块布把电视机 _蒙上_ 了。（３）去年我出差到重庆，正 _赶上_ 八月十五。（４）今天外边很冷，把大衣 _穿上_ 吧。（５）我今天一出门就  _遇上_ 了一场大雨。（６）前边有一个虫子，小心别 _踩上_ 。（７）请在卡片上 _写上_ 你的名字。（８）冰箱温度太低了，牛奶都 _冻上_ 冰了。（９）他把电脑折了，自己又 _装上_ 了。（１０）他 _看上_ 了那个女孩，可是那个女孩觉得他比不上她以前的男朋友。

Comment: ４。结果意义（二）：表示实现了预期的或希望达到的目的。例如：（１）他终于 _买上_ 了他喜欢的汽车。（２）我弟弟去年好不容易 _考上_ 了大学。（３）这个村子的居民去年才 _用上_ 水。（４）他借了很多钱，一直 _还不上_ 。＂上＂的这个结果意义是一种口语用法。５。状态意义：表示动作或状态的开始。例如：（１）老师刚说了一句话，学生们就 _议论上_ 了。（２）小明，我叫你睡觉，你怎么又 _唱上_ 了。（３）这个孩子时间抓得很紧，刚下课回到家，又 _用上_ 功了。（４）你不是在上学吗，怎么 _做上_ 生意了？

Comment: ［下］趋向意义（一）：表示人或物体通过动作由高出向低处移动。例如：（１）手 _放下_ 吧。（２）听见有人叫我，我很快 _走下_ 楼。 应注意下面两个句字：（３）孩子看见我，高兴地 _跳下_ 床。（４）孩子看见我，高兴地 _跳下_ 地。这两个句子表示的意义实际上一样。也就是说，＂下＂后的处所词可以表示动作的起点（例如（３））也可以表示动作的终点（例如（４））。当处所词表示的处所高于地平线时，它表示动作的起点，当处所词表示的处所为地平线或低于地平线时，它表示动作的终点。２。趋向意义（二）：表示通过动作，人或物体退离立足点。例如：（１）服务员 _端下_  一盘菜倒掉了。（吃饭的桌子是立足点）３。结果意义（一）：表示分离以至固定。例如：（１）他放下手术刀， _脱下_ 白大褂，走了出去。（２）孩子们 _采下_ 一束野花，送给老师。（３）她 _生下_ 孩子以后，精神好了一些。（４）结婚的日子已经 _定下_ 了，可是他还决定不了是不是要跟她结婚。４。结果意义（二）：表示＂凹陷＂。例如：（１）他很瘦，脸颊 _陷下_ 两个坑。５。结果意义（三）：表示＂容纳＂。例如：（１）我的钱包很小， _装不下_ 那么多钱。（２）这间屋子 _坐不下_ 一百个人。（３）他心里 _搁不下_ 事儿，老是坐立不安的。６。状态意义：表示由动态进入静态。例如：（１）我一喊，他就 _停下_  了。

Comment: （２）这几天我刚 _定下_  心写论文，你又来打扰我。（３）大家对你这么好，你怎么老也 _安不下_  心呢？ In particular, for 照得上 see ［上］ ３.（or  4.） ,for 停得下see ［下］5.。
bkrs: 天安门照得上照不上？ Умещается ли в кадре площадь Тяньаньмэнь? (Does Tiananmen fit into a/the picture (photograph)?

Comment: I believe this question is not about the tag [Classical Chinese]?

Answer (score 2):

停得下 = [**停** verb]+[**得** potential particle]+[**下** directional particle]

照得上 = [**照** verb]+[**得** potential particle]+[**上** directional particle]

In 广场上停得下:

- 停 is the verb for "to stop / to park"
- 得 is the potential particle for "able to"
- 下 is the directional particle for "down"

> 广场上停得**下**=  able to park **down** on the square

In 天安门照得上:

- 照 is the verb for "to take picture"
- 得 is the potential particle for "able to"
- 上 is the directional particle for "onto"

> 天安门照得**上** =  able to take picture of Tiananmen Square **onto**(the camera)

There are only two potential particles. They are "得" and "不" , so it is easy to remember. You potentially, either able to, or unable to preform an action (verb)

There are many more directional particles such as " up, down, in, out, "
we choose different directional particle depend on how a verb act on an object.

For example:

放上 (lay upon) - 放得上 / 放不上 (able/unable to lay it upon )

丢下 (drop down) - 丢得下 / 丢不下 (able/unable to drop it down)

插入 (insert in)- 插得入 / 插不入 (able/unable to insert it in)

取出 (take out) - 取得出 / 取不出 (able/unable to take it out)

*There are too many particles to explain them one by one. You just have to memorize each of them.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on the verb you use.
At first, I would suggest you to use 得下 with all verb cause in many case 得下is more common to combine with verbs.
Both of 得上, 得下 means be able to do (the verb) in your case,and in that means 得下 is more common instead of 得上.