# What does 一样 mean in "适度的睡眠时间与合理饮食，积极运动一样"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

In the following sentence:

> 研究成果认为，适度的睡眠时间与合理饮食、积极运动**一样**，能为人体补充能量，调节各项生理功能，降低患上心血管疾病的风险。

一样 usually means "like" or "the same as". However, I don't understand the meaning here.

I feel I understand the two points below correctly:

- Since it is an enumeration comma (、), 合理饮食 and 积极运动 can be concatenated.
- 与 then concatenates 适度的睡眠时间 and 合理饮食、积极运动.

However, then my questions are:

- How does the 一样 work here? Does it modify "合理饮食、积极运动" or just "积极运动" or the entire "适度的睡眠时间与合理饮食、积极运动"?
- What is the meaning of 一样 in this sentence?

I feel that *"A 与 B、C 一样"* mean *"A, and B and C as well"*, but am not sure...

Comment: BTW in "降低患上心血管疾病的风险", is 上 considered a result complement? 患 means "contract", and 患上 means "contract the disease (as a completed condition)"?

Comment: ＂上＂ functions as result complement to 患, the various uses/meanings of ＂上＂ as result complement have been discussed at this site before and can be looked up in grammars, e.g. ＂实用现代汉语语法＂

Comment: 与（跟，和）。。。、。。。一样，is basic grammar， see grammars on comparison,e.g."外国人实用汉语语法＂：用＂跟＂表示比较。一、用介词＂跟＂表示比较的意义。如果区别两个人或两种事物的异同，可以用介词＂跟＂引出比较的对象，再用谓语表示比较的结果。用＂跟＂表示比较的句子的基本格式是：＜比较的人或事物＞---＜介词＂跟＂＞---＜比较的人或事物＞---＜比较的结果（异同）＞例如：这张画跟那张画一样。他学的专业跟你学的专业一样。他的爱好跟我的爱好差不多。我的想法跟你的想法相同。去他那儿跟来我这儿一样。你买跟我买一样。

Comment: uses of 上 as complement of direction/result, see comments 1,2,3,4  at   https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/how-to-explain-usage-of-%e7%85%a7%e5%be%97%e4%b8%8a-%e7%ab%99%e5%be%97%e4%b8%8b

Comment: **适度的睡眠时间**与**合理饮食**、**积极运动**一样: **A** likes both **B** & **C**.

Answer (score 1):

适度的睡眠时间与合理饮食、积极运动一样

适度的睡眠时间 is the same as '合理饮食 and 积极运动'

Answer (score 1):

与 。。。 一样 = just like

研究成果认为，
Research shows
适度的睡眠时间与合理饮食、积极运动一样，
(that) the appropriate amount of sleep, just like a balanced diet and exercise,
能为人体补充能量，
can replenish one's strength,
调节各项生理功能，
regulate our physiological functions,
降低患上心血管疾病的风险。
and lower the risk of cardio-vascular disease.